# Xalan Java и русские буквы в имени файла

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

Хочу использовать Xalan-J для XSLT-преобразования (Java 8). Скачал библиотеку Xalan-J 2.7.2.
Есть основной файл с преобразованием main.xsl. Его я и указываю в качестве параметра для трансформера:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class App
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

    Transformer transformer = null;
    try
    {
        transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource("main.xsl"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource("test.xml"), new StreamResult( new FileOutputStream("out.htm")));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Но в файле main.xsl есть включаемое преобразование, назовем его Аванс.xsl:

```
 <xsl:include href="Аванс.xsl"/>
```

При попытке запустить приложение выдается ошибка:

```
(Неизвестное расположение или ошибка)org.apache.xml.utils.URI$MalformedURIException: В имени пути обнаружен недопустимый символ: А
```

То есть ругается на то, что файл с включаемым преобразованием начинается на русскую букву. Если заменить имя файла на латинские буквы, то всё ОК.

Как быть?

Comment: по стандарту uri должны состоять из букв английского алфавита, арабских цифр, "-", ".", "_" и "~", остальные символы должны кодироваться. Попробуйте заменить `Аванс.xsl` на `%D0%90%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81.xsl`

Answer (score 1):

Заменить имя файла на латинские буквы

:D

Comment: Невозможно. Разработанные преобразования изменять нельзя.